# array_rand not working correctly?

Tags: php, posts, wp-query, array

I want to show different content on each page refresh. To accomplish this, I've used the PHP [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) function.

I fetched posts and stored content in a value using the below code. When I output the value before `array_rand()`, it is showing first post content but in `array_rand()` if I output the random functionality is working but showing  some random number. I believe it's post count. The minimum num shown is 0 and max is 2 there are 3 posts.

Check this [here](http://204.236.224.159/vt/carwash/) and the code I used is.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'order'=> 'ASC',
        'orderby'=>'menu_order',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_type' => 'Didyouknows' 
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    $posts = $loop->get_posts();

    foreach($posts as $post){
        //print_r($loop);exit;
        //echo $loop->['ID'];

        $rval[]= $post->post_content;

        //print_r($rval);exit;
        //echo $loop[post_content];
        //print_r($rval);exit;

        $rand = array_rand($rval);
        //echo $rval[$rand[0]];
        //echo $rand;
    }
?>

<h2><?php echo $rand; ?></h2>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a single random post would be far more efficient than getting all posts, then plucking a random post from the query. Here's an updated [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instance using `'orderby' => rand`:

```
$args = array( 
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_type' => 'Didyouknows', // Post type names should never use capital letters, btw 
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) { $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_content(); ?></h2><?php
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

In your original code, you are seeing the values of 0, 1, and 2 which represent the possible keys for elements within your `$rval` array. You should move `$rand = array_rand($rval);` out of the `foreach` loop and do something like:

```
<h2><?php echo $rval[ $rand ]; ?></h2>
```

The fist solution using `WP_Query` and `'orderby' => 'rand'` is preferable though.

Comment: Thanks for the code and thanks for the tip worked like a gem, but any idea why array_rand didn't work?

Comment: You got it! Yeah, updated my answer to address that too. Please click accept if the issue has been resolved so that it's more clear to the next person that encounters the issue.

Comment: Wow...!! Thanks even the array_rand working. Sure I will use first method, thanks again :)